# Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Subscription' -angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, angular-http

I have been trying to get an array of objects from node to a service onInit and assign it to component. I am able to view data in service but when i try to assign to a variable in component, I get below error. I have included my code as well. Please favour on this.All i need is to just take that array from service and assign it to finallist in component.

```
ERROR in 

    C:/Users/girija/Documents/animapp/src/app/components/list.component.ts (28,5): Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
      Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Subscription'.
```

My code is below:
app.service.ts:

```
   public finallist=[]
     getList(){
          return this.http.get('/api/list').subscribe(data=>{
             this.finallist=JSON.parse(data['_body']);
             return this.finallist;
        })
        }
```

app.component.ts:

```
  totallist=[];
     ngOnInit() {
        this.totallist=this.someService.getList();

      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subscribe` returns `Subscription` object, this is not what you have looking for.

Try something like this:

app.service.ts

```
getList(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('/api/list').map(data => data['_body']);
}
```

app.component.ts

```
totallist=[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.someService.getList().subscribe(data => this.totallist = data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `map` operator to convert the response into json type

```
getList(){
          return this.http.get('/api/list')
             .map(response=> <Type>response.json()) /////////
             .subscribe(data=>{
             this.finallist=JSON.parse(data['_body']);
             return this.finallist;
        })
        }
```

**Note : `<Type>` is used for strict typing**

Answer (score 0):

See my answer below. It explains to you how to get your data from the server, to service, and finally to component. [Receiving Jason instead of html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121284/angular-2-mean-stack-receiving-json-instead-of-html/41353912#41353912). I am using mongodB but your backend may be different. Hope this helps.