# Angular MatTableDataSource Error

Tags: angular, mean

I got an error like this :

> [ts] Argument of type 'Company' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Company[]'.   Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Company'.

When I'd like to insert an Array Object into MatTableDataSource. This is my TypeScript file :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { CompanyService } from '../../../services/company.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../../services/auth.service';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { Company } from '../../../models/company.model';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-index-company',
  templateUrl: './index-company.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index-company.component.css']
})

export class IndexCompanyComponent implements OnInit {
  company   : Object;
  companies : Object;
  displayedColumns = ['perusahaan', 'kategori', 'mahasiswa', 'option'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Company>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); 
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue; 
  }
  constructor(
    private companyService: CompanyService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  )
  {
      this.companyService.getCompanies().subscribe(companies => {
      this.companies = companies;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(companies);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And this is my Company models :

```
export class Company{
    perusahaan       : String;
    alamat           : String;
    deskripsi        : String;
    telepon          : String;
    email_perusahaan : String;
    website          : String;
    students         = [];
    kategori         : String;
    author           : String;
    update_by        : String;
    status           : String;
}
```

Edited. CompanyService addded :

```
  getCompanies(): Observable<Company>{
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get(this.baseUri+'/companies', {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you have a type error. try this `companies : Array<Company>;`

Comment: It looks like companyService.getCompanies() returns an array of companies, and yet MatTableDataSource<Company> requires a single company. You might want to set this to be MatTableDataSource<Company[]>.

Comment: After I tried, it just got same error on this.companies. I did MatTableDataSource<Company[]>, but still no change.

Comment: When I try to console.log(companies), it returns an array with two objects inside like this : [{…}, {…}]

Comment: I can't find anything wrong in your code right now. Does the error come when the page is loaded? is it when the service is called? do you have an idea of what line it could be? The error looks like there might be a possible typing error with your service, here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782739/property-includes-is-missing-in-type-subscription-angular2?rq=1) of how someone else solved it

Comment: The filter is working on my page, but it gives error on my terminal when I compile it. And I can't run ng build while the error still occur.

Comment: Just this error make me can't do ng build. ERROR in src/app/admin/admin-companies/admin-companies.component.ts(49,48): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Company' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Company[]'.
src/app/company/index-company/index-company.component.ts(42,48): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Company' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Company[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Company'.

Comment: can you share your CompanyService code?

Comment: CompanyService has been added. To Vikas.

Comment: This is odd. I have the same problem with Angular 8 + Material. I get the terminal error: XArray[]' is missing the following properties from type 'MatTableDataSource<unknown>'...BUT it works and builds. If I follow the Angular material notes and restore to getting the data direct (via a const) then the error goes away.

Answer (score 11):

TypeScript became more strict last months, so now solution is:

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any[]> = new MatTableDataSource<any[]>([]);
```

Or you can disable `--strictPropertyInitialization`

Comment: In my case changing it to following solved the issue:


  ```tableData: MatTableDataSource<ArrivalReportInterface> = new MatTableDataSource<ArrivalReportInterface>([]);```

Comment: Yea it looks like you don't need to provide an array (`[]`) in the type when using MatTableDataSource. Assign to `dataSource` variable can work like: `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Transactions>(data);` Where the `data` variable is of type `Transactions[]`.

Answer (score 6):

I have the similar problem before.
I solved the problem by setting

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any[]>;
```

then

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(companies);
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error by adding /table at the end of the import:

```
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your datasource like this:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.trainingService.getData());

@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
constructor(private trainingService: TrainingService) {}
```

then implement ngAfterViewInit witch is imported from @angular/core

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material version 16.2 supports Observable so you don't need the async pipe