# Getting Json data from nested api response & show in a table

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-core, response, jsonconvert

I'm getting the response from my API like-

```
0:
action: "Add"
date: "2021-09-22T00:00:00"
level: 1
module: "[Mode001]"
oldRecord: "{\"Code\": 7,\"Name\": \"F0002\",\"Type\": \"Feat}"
newRecord: "{\"Code\": 7,\"Name\": \"F0001\",\"Type\": \"Feature}"
remark: null
```

Here, all the field values are received as string. I want to show the oldRecord & newRecord fields  in separate table.

**Component code-**

```
this.searchPendings = this.service.get(obj).subscribe(res => {
      this.dataSource = res.apiData;
      console.log(res.apiData); 
      // I want to extract the oldRecord & newRecord from the res.apiData to work further
      var anyt = JSON.parse(res.apiData) // throws error in console
    })
```

How can I convert the two **specific field values** from string to Json & show it in a table like-

| newRecord | oldRecord |
| --- | --- |
| Name: F0002 | Name: F0001 |

Comment: `JSON.parse()` doesn't do what you need ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a string to JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976897/converting-a-string-to-json-object)

Comment: can you please drop some code which you have written

Comment: @Elikill58 I have another api response as string in the api response. First of all, I cannnot **extract** the **specific two fields** from the response. Then I don't know how to convert the string values into json & show them in a table (with proper header means the object key & values in the body)

Comment: @RishabVaigankar I've added the code that is fetching the data from my API.

Comment: which error it throw ? Because your exact string isn't valid json, there is the last `\"` which is missing

Comment: @Elikill58 `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` I've modified your answer & applied `var oldRecord =res.apiData["oldRecord"];` instead. It also shows the same error !

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022178/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-json) answer your last issue ?

Comment: @Elikill58 no it didn't. I found another way to fix that. Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: Ok, for this, you can self-answer your question, and mark your own as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the required value that will be the json in string format, then convert it such as :

```js
var apiJson = {
   action: "Add",
   date: "2021-09-22T00:00:00",
   level: 1,
   module: "[Mode001]",
   oldRecord: "{\"Code\": 7,\"Name\": \"F0002\",\"Type\": \"Feat\"}",
   newRecord: "{\"Code\": 7,\"Name\": \"F0001\",\"Type\": \"Feature\"}",
   remark: null
}; // begin with your data

var oldRecord = apiJson["oldRecord"]; // get required record
var oldRecordJson = JSON.parse(oldRecord); // convert it from string to json
console.log(oldRecordJson["Name"]); // get name and print
```

For your exact code it will be:

```
this.searchPendings = this.service.get(obj).subscribe(res => {
     this.dataSource = res.apiData;
     var oldRecord = this.dataSource["oldRecord"];
     var oldRecordJson = JSON.parse(oldRecord);
     console.log(oldRecordJson["Name"]);
})
```

PS: WARN if it return you a list of item instead of only one. The response from your API seems not exact/not valid json

Comment: The `var oldRecord = this.dataSource["oldRecord"];` shows "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"oldRecord"' can't be used to index type 'MatTableDataSource<any>'. Property 'oldRecord' does not exist on type 'MatTableDataSource<any>'.ts(7053)" error !

Comment: It's because of the `dataSource` type. Here it's mainly in your hand, I don't know all of your environment. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995170/angular-mattabledatasource-error) that can help you