# Angular 4 MEAN stack get length of Observable

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angular, typescript

I use a service function in my Angular 4 app to retrieve data from the MongoDB/Express.js backend:

```
getArticles() {
  return this.http.get('api/articles').map(res => res.json());
}
```

How do I get the length of the received array?

**Update:**

I should have clarified, I needed to find a length of an Observable array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Length of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object). If you're just looking for the length of an object, that question has been asked and answered dozens, if not hundreds, of times on here. In short, `var size = Object.keys(myObj).length;`

Comment: Try this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121284/angular-2-mean-stack-receiving-json-instead-of-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40237063/5861479
In my case it would be something like this:

```
getArticlesLength() {
  return this.http.get('api/articles')
    .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(result => {console.log(result.length)});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`var size = Object.keys(myObj).length;`. Object.keys() 'returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties', from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). So if you do `Object.keys(myObj)` you will get an array of enumerable properties. Doing `.length` on that array will provide you with the number of enumerable properties.